# How to prevent large number of downloads of a certain file with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, download, bots

I need to know how to prevent repetitive file downloads using .htaccess, or if not via .htaccess than some other method.

A site I maintain had over 9,000 hits on a single PDF file, accounting for over 80% of the site's total bandwidth usage, and I believe that most of the hits were from the same IP address. I've banned the IP, but that's obviously not an effective solution because there are always proxies and besides, I can only do that after the fact.

So what I want to do is cap the number of times a single IP can attempt to download a designated file or file type over a given period of time. Can this be done with .htaccess? If not, what other options do I have?

EDIT: The suggestion that I redirect requests to a server-side script that would track requests by IP via database sounds like a good option. Can anyone recommend an existing script or library?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some server side code stream out your files, you have the opportunity to control what's being sent.  I'm not aware of a .htaccess solution (which doesn't mean there isn't one).

My background is in Microsoft products, so I'd write a bit of ASP.NET code that would accept the filename as a parameter & stream back the result.  Since it would be my code, I could easily access a database to track which IP I was serving, how often the file was sent, etc.

This could easily be done using any server side tech - PHP, etc.

Comment: So I could, say, redirect all PDF requests to a PHP script which would return the original file as a header as long as the limit wasn't exceeded? Tracking it via database isn't the most fun solution I can think of, but I can see how it would get the job done.

Comment: That's the general idea.  Database might be overkill; it depends on your particular solution.  The cool part is that with the PHP script you'd at least have options.